# Make streaming via ffmpeg of the screen recorder of android

Tags: ffmpeg, android, streaming, adb

I can record screen via this command then read the content in streamin via ffplay:

```
adb exec-out screenrecord --bit-rate=16m --output-format=h264 --size 800x600 - | ffplay -framerate 60 -framedrop -bufsize 16M -
```

But how to stream this record via ffmpeg

Comment: You may want to edit your question and clarify how you intend the media to be consumed (i.e. how will people viewing the stream access it?). Any commands for `ffmpeg` will likely need to be based around that (that is, there are a number of ways to output video from `ffmpeg`).

Comment: the command "adb exec-out screenrecord --bit-rate=16m --output-format=h264 --size 800x600 -" allows us to receive data (screenrecord) how I can instead read it via the command "ffplay -framerate 60 -framedrop -bufsize 16M -", but i want to broadcast (stream via rtp / http ...) this data (screenrecord)